# Sum of two complex numbers using operator overloading

Tags: c++, constructor

I am pretty new to the concept of operator overloading,I am trying to add two complex numbers using operator overloading concept and getting an error:

> "no matching function for call to ‘Complex::Complex()’ Complex obj;".

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Complex
{
  int re_,im_;
  public:
  Complex(int re,int im):re_(re),im_(im) {};
  Complex operator+(const Complex &c)
  {
    Complex obj;
    obj.re_=re_+c.re_;
    obj.im_=im_+c.im_;
    return obj;
  }

};
int main()
{
  int re1,im1,re2,im2;
  cin>>re1>>im1>>re2>>im2;
  Complex c1(re1,im1);
  Complex c2(re2,im2);
  Complex c3;
  c3=c1+c2;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're missing a default constructor.

Comment: won't compiler provides free default constructor? as it normally does.

Comment: Not if you define a constructor yourself.

Comment: BTW your class & variable names are not good.

Comment: why compiler dosen't provide free default constructor?

Comment: `Complex c3;` requires a constructor that accepts no arguments.  There is none.  When another constructor is declared/defined, generation of a constructor that accepts no arguments is suppressed.

Comment: *"why compiler dosen't provide free default constructor"* Because you wrote your  own constructor.

Comment: It only provides a default constructor when there are no other constructors available. If you define ANY (it doesn't have to take no arguments) constructor yourself (as you did in this case) then the compiler will not add another as there is no reason to assume another constructor is needed.

Comment: after adding default constructor also its showing an error:----->/tmp/ccnyuI1H.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `Complex::Complex()'
/tmp/ccnyuI1H.o: In function `Complex::operator+(Complex const&)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN7ComplexplERKS_[_ZN7ComplexplERKS_]+0x18): undefined reference to `Complex::Complex()'

Comment: why undefined refrence?

Comment: Because you declared it instead of defining it. Use `Complex() {}` or `Complex() = default;` (the meaning is slightly different, but it's not revelant here).

Comment: Please don't post long errors in the comments, it's difficult to read, instead you can edit the question (preferably by adding the new things at the end and not overwriting everything). Also include the code that you've added. I'll assume you get this error because you wrote a line like: `Complex();`? And that's now what you want, as @HolyBlackCat pointed out.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_overloading.htm

Comment: it worked thanks to all...i am new to stack overflow if you don't mind please tell is it good to thanks in reply

Comment: @Ayush https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a default constructor. Use your custom one:

```
Complex operator+(const Complex &c)
{
    return Complex{re_+c.re_, im_+c.im_};
}
```

and

```
Complex c3 = c1 + c2;
```